# Array Map to a unique key after discretization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have A 1D numpy observation array  example [a,b,c,d].
a,b,c,d takes continous values, with each of them belonging to different finite domain.Example a lies from -2. to 2. etc.

My goal is to map any such observation to a single number.
Example [1,2,-3,4] and [1,2,-2.7,4] gets mapped to same number x, with the help of discretization.
Also [1 0 0 1] and [0 1 1 0 ] should be mapped to seperate unique numbers!

How would i go about this with numpy.

Comment: Could you please share what is the expected output for [1,2,-3,4]?

Answer (score 0):

If your discretization process is taking the nearest whole number (rounding towards minus infinity rather than towards zero) then you could do something like this

```
>>> a = np.array([-1.6, -0.5, 1.2, 2.2])
>>> (np.floor(a + 0.5) * [1000, 100, 10, 1]).sum()
-1988.0
```